# WCF server side crash CommunicationObjectFaultedException:

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, client-server

WCF service (server) is running fine for some time, but than it unexpectedly crashes with exception, this exception is logged in **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException**:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1+SecurityReplySessionChannel[System.ServiceModel.Channels.IReplySessionChannel], cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfFaulted()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.StartInnerReceive()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.OnFaultSent()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.OnInnerReceiveDone()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.StartInnerReceive()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.Start()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveRequestAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult.ReceiveMessage(Object state)
   at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

There's no xml configuration, everything is configured at runtime.
Service context is Single, concurrency is Multiple.

We've disabled replay detection. Our users had many problems with wrong datetime set on their PCs, so we were forced to "disable" time skew.
Net.Tcp binding is used for communication, we're using callbacks.

Custom error handler is used, HandleError always returns false.

**Current solution:** Service is set to restart automatically after crash, but that's more than unsatisfying.

---

**Configuration (constant variables replaced by value):**

```
Uri tcpBaseAddress = new Uri(String.Format("net.tcp://localhost:{0}", MyMwcNetworkingConstants.NETWORKING_PORT_MASTER_SERVER_NEW));

// create the net.tcp binding for the service endpoint
NetTcpBinding ntcBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
ntcBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
ntcBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 1024*1024;
ntcBinding.MaxBufferSize = 10*1024;
ntcBinding.MaxConnections = 500;
ntcBinding.ListenBacklog = 500;
ntcBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10*1024;
ntcBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 10*1024;
ntcBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 10*1024;
ntcBinding.SendTimeout = 90s;
ntcBinding.ReceiveTimeout = 90s;
ntcBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
ntcBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
ntcBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
ntcBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.None;

m_host = new System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost(Service, tcpBaseAddress);
m_host.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new MyUserValidator();
m_host.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
m_host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(MyMasterConstants.MASTER_CERTIFICATE, string.Empty);
m_host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CustomCertificateValidator = new MyCertificateValidator(String.Empty);
m_host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

var endpoint = m_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyMasterService), MyCustomBinding.DecorateBinding(ntcBinding, MyMasterConstants.WCF_MAX_CLIENT_COUNT), tcpBaseAddress);
m_host.Open();
```

**There's my custom binding:**

```
public static class MyCustomBinding
{
    public static Binding DecorateBinding(Binding binding, int? maxNegotiationCount)
    {
        CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding(binding);
        SymmetricSecurityBindingElement security = customBinding.Elements.Find<SymmetricSecurityBindingElement>();
        if (security != null)
        {
            security.IncludeTimestamp = false;
            security.LocalClientSettings.DetectReplays = false;
            security.LocalServiceSettings.DetectReplays = false;
            security.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            security.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            security.LocalClientSettings.SessionKeyRenewalInterval = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            security.LocalServiceSettings.SessionKeyRenewalInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Int32.MaxValue);

            if (maxNegotiationCount.HasValue)
            {
                security.LocalServiceSettings.MaxPendingSessions = maxNegotiationCount.Value;
                security.LocalServiceSettings.MaxStatefulNegotiations = maxNegotiationCount.Value;
            }

            // Get the System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters
            SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters secureTokenParams = (SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters)security.ProtectionTokenParameters;

            // From the collection, get the bootstrap element.
            SecurityBindingElement bootstrap = secureTokenParams.BootstrapSecurityBindingElement;

            // Set the MaxClockSkew on the bootstrap element.
            bootstrap.IncludeTimestamp = false;
            bootstrap.LocalClientSettings.DetectReplays = false;
            bootstrap.LocalServiceSettings.DetectReplays = false;
            bootstrap.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            bootstrap.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            bootstrap.LocalClientSettings.SessionKeyRenewalInterval = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            bootstrap.LocalServiceSettings.SessionKeyRenewalInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Int32.MaxValue);

            if (maxNegotiationCount.HasValue)
            {
                bootstrap.LocalServiceSettings.MaxPendingSessions = maxNegotiationCount.Value;
                bootstrap.LocalServiceSettings.MaxStatefulNegotiations = maxNegotiationCount.Value;
            }

            return customBinding;
        }
        else
        {
            return binding;
        }
    }

    public static Binding DecorateBinding(Binding binding)
    {
        return DecorateBinding(binding, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Faulted-State could mean many things (not possible to parse configuration etc.).
Change the binding to basicHttpBinding - its easier to debug.

Comment: Configure WCF tracing to get more detailed erro messages. Like Peter said Faulted-State could mean many things.

Comment: @PeterLarsen'CPH': I'm not able to reproduce this issue on DEV, it can be reproduced only on PRODUCTION. And I can't definitely change binding on production. I'll try to reproduce on DEV, but it takes a lot of various requests and quite long time to reproduce. It crashes about once a day on production.

Comment: You need more information about the error: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/govindr/archive/2006/11/01/debugging-wcf-traces-and-message-logs.aspx - like Strukov said !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in the exact same situation as you (WCF service crashes randomly on Production, cannot replicate in Dev, stack trace is identical to yours). I've found the following KB, and going to give it a try soon: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600907/en-us. The "this hotfix hasn't been fully tested" stops me from applying it right now.

Let me know if you try it, and it resolves your problem. Hope this helps.